# не получается отсортировать имена массива обьектов в зависимости от количества их друзей

Tags: javascript

не могу понять как правильно отсортовать массив имен (поле name) людей,  в зависимости от количества их друзей (поле friends). Я использую метод sort. но мне выводит массив обьектов. Вот мой код

```js
'use strict';
const users = [
  {
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
  },
  {
    id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
    name: 'Sharlene Bush',
    email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 34,
  },
  {
    id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
    name: 'Ross Vazquez',
    email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
    name: 'Elma Head',
    email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    id: '334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70',
    name: 'Carey Barr',
    email: 'careybarr@nurali.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Jordan Sampson', 'Eddie Strong'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    skills: ['ex', 'culpa', 'nostrud'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 27,
  },
  {
    guid: '150b00fb-dd82-427d-9faf-2879ea87c695',
    name: 'Blackburn Dotson',
    email: 'blackburndotson@furnigeer.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Jacklyn Lucas', 'Linda Chapman'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    skills: ['non', 'amet', 'ipsum'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 38,
  },
  {
    id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
    name: 'Sheree Anthony',
    email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 39,
  },
];

const getNamesSortedByFriendsCount = users => {
  return users.sort((a, b) => a.name - b.friends);
};

console.log(getNamesSortedByFriendsCount(users));
```

Вроде бы ничего сложного но никак не получается реализовать этот метод

Comment: Java и Javascript - это разные языки, не имеющие ничего общего.

Comment: Извините, я просто всегда выбирала Java. Большое спасибо что подметили больше ни буду делать такую ошыбку.

Comment: Внутри функции `sort` a и b - два сравниваемых элемента массива. Ну допустим `a.name` будет 'Sheree Anthony', `b.friends` - ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker']. Ну и как теперь от имени-строки отнимать массив?) Вся идея сортировки в том, чтобы возвращать любое положительное число, если одно больше другого, или отрицательное, если наоборот. Если сортировка должна быть по длине массива-друзей, соответственно и надо возвращать `a.friends.length - b.friends.length`

Comment: У меня сначала было a.friends - b.friends это потом я уже пришла в ступор и поэтому написала такую ерунду)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=> a.friends.length - b.friends.length - заменил на это ... ну и проверку нужно добавить что бы  friends  были всегда массивами

```js
const users = [
  {
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
  },
  {
    id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
    name: 'Sharlene Bush',
    email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 34,
  },
  {
    id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
    name: 'Ross Vazquez',
    email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
    name: 'Elma Head',
    email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    id: '334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70',
    name: 'Carey Barr',
    email: 'careybarr@nurali.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Jordan Sampson', 'Eddie Strong'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    skills: ['ex', 'culpa', 'nostrud'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 27,
  },
  {
    guid: '150b00fb-dd82-427d-9faf-2879ea87c695',
    name: 'Blackburn Dotson',
    email: 'blackburndotson@furnigeer.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Jacklyn Lucas', 'Linda Chapman'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    skills: ['non', 'amet', 'ipsum'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 38,
  },
  {
    id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
    name: 'Sheree Anthony',
    email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 39,
  },
];

const getNamesSortedByFriendsCount = users => {
  return users.sort((a, b) => a.friends.length - b.friends.length);
};

console.log(getNamesSortedByFriendsCount(users));
```

Comment: Аффтару скорее всего нужно дописать `.map( e => e.name );` после сортировки, чтобы вывести массив имен)

Comment: ну вопрос то стоял -  как правильно отсортировать

Comment: Спасибо все ваши подсказки очень к стати) Поэтому  всем +)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME - экстрасенс)))блин)